# call upload controller, but error will appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm coding with Ruby on rails 2.3.2 under BitNami RubyStack
When i call the upload controller, i get error like this:

compile error
C:/Users/BitNami RubyStack projects/killerapp/app/views/upload/index.html.erb:6: unterminated string meets end of file
C:/Users/BitNami RubyStack projects/killerapp/app/views/upload/index.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'

The code of index view:

{ :multipart => true } do |form| %> 
 First_Name: 
  
 Last_Name:

What's the problem? Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

When I used 1.9 The problem didn't appear, but i like to use ruby 1.8.7